# Get number of impressions for someone else's page on facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I would like to get number of impressions for someone else's (**not mine**) facebook page. Is it possible via graph or FQL api or any other means without having administrative access to the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. From the insights api documentation -

> Without a session, an application can retrieve only its own metrics. With a user session, it is possible to retrieve data for all applications, pages, and domains **owned by the session user**. Reading this data requires the read_insights permission.

Facebook API link - http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/insights/